# TortoiseHG repository explorer/annotate files

Tags: tortoisehg

My development group recently upgraded from version 1.1.9 to 2.8.1.  I mostly used Hg command line tools, but the two tortoise tools that I did regularly use, Repository Explorer and Annotate Files appear to have greatly changed with the newer version.  Repository Explorer seems to have become Revision History, and although Annotate Files is still there, it isn't as functional.

In 1.1.9, I could right-click on a file, and choose Repository Explorer.  This would open a window that had 3 sections.  On the top, it would list all the revisions for that particular file. On the bottom, there were 2 sections.  One showed all of the files that were part of that commit, and on the right it showed the changes for that file and revision.  In 2.8.1, Revision History only has the list of revisions, and the changes for that particular file and revision.  The related files aren't listed.

Similarly, in 1.1.9 Annotate Files, there was a top window that showed all of the revisions for that file, and then a bottom window that annotated the file for the selected revision.  In 2.8.1, it only shows the bottom window, along with a description of the Changeset.  Through the Changeset dialog, I can walk through the parent(s)/child(ren), but that is a really tedious way to navigate if there are numerous changes.

I've explored the new Workbench in 2.8.1, but I can't mimic the 1.1.9 functionality there, either.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

p.s. I did just discover the 'View -> Revision Details' in 2.8.1 that shows the other files within a ChangeSet.  But the Revision pane in the Workbench still shows the revisions for the entire repository, and not a particular file.  Unless I click on the file and select 'Revision History' which opens a separate window, and then doesn't show the related files.

Answer (score 0):

```
thg log the_name_of _your_file
```

Seems to be what you are looking for - it follows the history of a single file.